# Parse JSON into New Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, json, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset like below. ColB is in json format.

```
Date         ColA    ColB
2021-06-23  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "aaaaaa" }, { "element": "bbbbb" } ] } ]
2021-06-24  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "cccccc" }, { "element": "ddddd" } ] } ]
2021-06-24  UserB    [ { "list": [ { "element": "eeeeee" } ] } ]
```

How do I parse out this dataset so that each element becomes it's own row?

Expected output is below:

```
Date         ColA    ColB                                                                ColC
2021-06-23  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "aaaaaa" }, { "element": "bbbbb" } ] } ] aaaaaa
2021-06-23  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "aaaaaa" }, { "element": "bbbbb" } ] } ] bbbbb
2021-06-24  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "cccccc" }, { "element": "ddddd" } ] } ] cccccc
2021-06-24  UserA    [ { "list": [ { "element": "cccccc" }, { "element": "ddddd" } ] } ] ddddd
2021-06-24  UserB    [ { "list": [ { "element": "eeeeee" } ] } ]                         eeeeee
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this but no luck: `parse_json(session_id.value:list.element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement on line 5 below will give you the results you request.  If it is not safe to hardcode element zero in ColB, you use multiple `,lateral flatten()` statements (e.g. `, lateral flatten(ColB) l1, lateral flatten(l1.value:list) l2` which in this example produces the same results.)

```
with tbl as (select column1 Date, column2 ColA, parse_json(column3) ColB from (values
('2021-06-23', 'UserA', '[ { "list": [ { "element": "aaaaaa" }, { "element": "bbbbb" } ] } ]'),
('2021-06-24','UserA','[ { "list": [ { "element": "cccccc" }, { "element": "ddddd" } ] } ]'),
('2021-06-24','UserB','[ { "list": [ { "element": "eeeeee" } ] } ]')))
select Date, ColA, ColB, l2.value ColC from tbl, lateral flatten(ColB) l1, lateral flatten(l1.value:list) l2;

DATE    COLA    COLB    COLC
2021-06-23  UserA   [    {      "list": [        {          "element": "aaaaaa"        },        {          "element": "bbbbb"        }      ]    }  ]  {    "element": "aaaaaa"  }
2021-06-23  UserA   [    {      "list": [        {          "element": "aaaaaa"        },        {          "element": "bbbbb"        }      ]    }  ]  {    "element": "bbbbb"  }
2021-06-24  UserA   [    {      "list": [        {          "element": "cccccc"        },        {          "element": "ddddd"        }      ]    }  ]  {    "element": "cccccc"  }
2021-06-24  UserA   [    {      "list": [        {          "element": "cccccc"        },        {          "element": "ddddd"        }      ]    }  ]  {    "element": "ddddd"  }
2021-06-24  UserB   [    {      "list": [        {          "element": "eeeeee"        }      ]    }  ] {    "element": "eeeeee"  }
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! The last part is adding in column C that would correspond to the element value

Comment: I added ColC for ya